# Help with solving ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is actually a part of an SDE problem, which I am having problem to solve. However i think it requires only ODE knowledge to solve. I have

$$\mu(u) = x^3 + 3 \int_t^u a \mu(s) ds + 3 \sigma^2 \int_t^u xe^{a(s-t)}ds$$

Now taking derivatives w.r.t $u$ we obtain the following ODE for $\mu$

$$\dot{\mu}(u) = 3a\mu(u) + 3\sigma^2xe^{a(u-t)}$$

And plugging in $u=t$ both integrals cancel, so
$$\mu(t) = x^3$$

The solution to the ODE should be:

$$\mu(u) = x^3e^{3a(u-t)}+ \frac{3\sigma^2x}{2a}e^{3a(u-t)}-\frac{3\sigma^2x}{2a}e^{a(u-t)}$$

---

Now what i have done i first i solve the homogenous equation

$$d\mu_h = 3a\mu_h ds$$

I get

$$\mu_h = x^3e^{3a(u-t)}$$

Now when solving the rest of the equation i get:

$$d\mu = 3\sigma^2xe^{a(u-t)}ds$$

Which could be solved quite straight-forward:

$$\mu = 3\sigma^2x \int_t^ue^{a(u-s)}ds = 3\sigma^2x[-\frac{e^{a(u-s)}}{a}]_t^u = 3\sigma^2x \frac{1}{a}(e^{a(u-t)}-1)$$

Now putting them together i do not get the same solution as asked for.

i.e.

$$\mu_h + \mu = x^3e^{3a(u-t)} + 3\sigma^2x \frac{1}{a}(e^{a(u-t)}-1)$$

Which is not the same as:

$$\mu(u) = x^3e^{3a(u-t)}+ \frac{3\sigma^2x}{2a}e^{3a(u-t)}-\frac{3\sigma^2x}{2a}e^{a(u-t)}$$

Does anyone know where the error in reasoning is?

Answer (score 2):

Your error is in believing that if
$\mu=\alpha+\beta$ with
$$\alpha'(u)=3a\alpha(u)\quad(H)$$ and $\beta'(u)=f(u),$ then $$\mu'(u)=3a\mu(u)+f(u)\quad(E).$$ There is no reason for that. What is true is that the solutions of $(E)$ are $\mu=\alpha+\gamma$ where $\alpha$ is the general solution of $(H)$ and $\gamma$ is a particular solution of $(E).$

Besides, your initial condition must not be applied to $\alpha$ but to $\mu,$ once $(E)$ is completely solved.

In your example, $\alpha(u)=Ce^{3au}$ with $C\in\Bbb R,$ and you can look for some particular solution $\gamma$ by writing it a priori
$$\gamma(u)=C(u)e^{3au}$$
thereby simplifying $(E)$ to
$$C'(u)e^{3au}=f(u)=Ae^{au}$$
i.e. $C'(u)=Ae^{-2au},$
where $$A= 3\sigma^2xe^{-at}.$$ A particular solution of $(E)$ is therefore
$$\gamma(u)=-\frac A{2a}e^{au}$$
and the general solution is
$$\mu(u)=Ce^{3au}-\frac A{2a}e^{au}$$ with $C$ determined by the initial condition: $$x^3=\mu(t)=Ce^{3at}-\frac A{2a}e^{at},$$
so that finally,
$$\begin{align}\mu(u)&=x^3e^{3a(u-t)}+\frac A{2a}e^{3au-2at}
-\frac A{2a}e^{au}\\&=
x^3e^{3a(u-t)}+ \frac{3\sigma^2x}{2a}e^{3a(u-t)}-\frac{3\sigma^2x}{2a}e^{a(u-t)}.\end{align}$$